# Calling a secure WCF Service from Javascript

Tags: javascript, wcf

This should be a simple question.

Is it actually possible to call a secure WCF service from Javascript.

I've searched all over the internet, but all I find is messages like those below:

[Link to messages](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1306f06-b4f6-4f6c-abf8-e8f47d42affa/calling-secure-wcf-method-from-javascript-ajax?forum=wcf)

Comment: Technically, since a WCF service should be platform agnostic, if you want to consume it from JS, it should be communicate via a web server first.  Nonetheless, you can follow this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33234/A-beginner-s-guide-for-consuming-a-WCF-service-in

Comment: I'm not sure that article describes calling a secure service.